# Download listener in symbian60

Tags: symbian

Is it possible to monitor the HTTP download operation in symbian.
I mean is it possible to know the successful download in symbian.
I am a new geek. Please help me.
Provide some suggestion.
I am using Symbian 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out RConnectionMonitor class.

(P.S. There is no point in starting to learn Symbian - it's dead platform)